# How do I set two gateways for one ethernet card in linux?

Tags: linux

How do I setup two gateways for one Ethernet card in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive what exactly you want to accomplish.  If you want to have two gateways for a single subnet then you might be able to use the route command.

route add -net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.255.0 gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Or if you want a computer to have two different ip addresses and use a seperate gw for each ip you can use network alias's and the route command.